# At least 2 for SQL and Tuples

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have a question related to SQL and Relational Calculus with Tuples.

I was wondering if there is a way to declare an "at least 2" statement in Tuples. It can be written in SQL for convenience as Tuples and SQL have a similar syntax.

First, lets asume the model is:

> Provider (1) ------ (*) Order // A provider has many orders, an order belongs to one provider
>
> Article(1) ------- (*) Order // An article belongs to many orders, every order is of one article.

- Provider has (ID_Prov)
- Article has (ID_Art)
- Order has (ID_Prov, ID_Art)

And the Query to Solve is:

> Get the ID of all the PROVIDERS with ID != 5 that delivered **at least two**   articles delivered by the PROVIDER with ID = 5.

The problem is that in SQL there are tools such as HAVING, GROUP BY, DISTINCT and COUNT that would make this as easy as:

```
    SELECT O1.ID_PROV FROM ORDER O1 JOIN ORDER O2 ON
    O1.ID_ART = O2.ID_ART 
    WHERE O1.ID_PROV != 5 AND O2.ID_PROV = 5
    GROUP BY O1.ID_PROV
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT O1.ID_ART) > 1;
```

But in Relational Calculus with Tuples there are no such tools. So this could be interpreted as trying to create the SQL for "At least two" without using COUNT, HAVING, DISTINCT and GROUP BY; **just Joins, Select and Where.**

I already made several attempts but failed in some details.

My closest attempt was:

```
SELECT O3.ID_PROV FROM ORDER O1, ORDER O2, ORDER O3 WHERE 
O1.ID_PROV = 5 
AND O2.ID_PROV != 5 
AND O3.ID_PROV != 5 
AND O1.ID_ART = O2.ID_ART 
AND O1.ID_ART = O3.ID_ART
AND O2.ID_PROV = O3.ID_PROV;
```

The problem with this is:

Lets say this is the table of orders:

ID_PROV......ID_ART

5.........................1

5 ........................2

1.........................1

1.........................1

3.........................1

3.........................2

My attempt will count Provider-1 as a result. Even if he only delivered one of the articles because he delivered it twice.
And correctly, it will also return provider-3.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the length, I was trying to be as clear as possible.

Comment: so..only `3` should be the result of your query per the sample data?

Comment: Yes, in that example only 3 should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the SQL query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o3.id_prov
FROM order o1 
INNER JOIN order o2 ON o2.id_prov = o1.id_prov AND o1.id_art <> o2.id_art
INNER JOIN order o3 ON o3.id_prov <> o1.id_prov AND o3.id_art = o1.id_art
INNER JOIN order o4 ON o4.id_prov = o3.id_prov AND o4.id_art = o2.id_art
WHERE o1.id_prov = 5
```

I'm using DISTINCT since a relation is a set and can't contain the same tuple multiple times, while SQL allows duplicate rows.

In the query, o1 and o2 select two different articles from the same provider.  o3 and o4 looks for the same two articles from a different provider.  Finally, I restrict the first provider to id_prov = 5.

Comment: Would you care to explain a little what is going on here? I'm trying to wrap my head around it but I'm just too new to SQL and Querys in general. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for not responding to your comments, I went to bed shortly after answering.  I added an explanation for future readers.